# Pass data from JS to PHP via XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm confronting now with a problem, which consists in sending a JS object to PHP, and I found that it should be done via `HtmlHttpRequest`, but the problem is that I'm a novice in PHP,and furthermore, I do not understand very well how this `XmlHttpRequest` works. I've tried different methods but, the one which I found suitable for me, returns constantly the same error. The code will be posted below, and now about the problem, I canperform this request, but when I perform this, the PHP side returns me an error message that there exists an undefined index.

And here's the desired code

JS part :

```
function createTransaction() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var newTransaction = {"name": document.getElementById('wallets').value}
    newTransaction.data = {
        "transactionID": document.getElementById('trans-id').value,
        "time": document.getElementById('creation-time').value,
        "senders": getSenders(),
        "receivers": getReceivers(),
        "finalSum": setSum()
    };
    xmlhttp.open('POST', '/admin.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 || this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText); // echo from php
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send({newTransaction});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newTransaction));
}
```

A short description : In this function I'm generating a an object, then send to PHP via `XmlHttpRequest` using a `POST` request, that's all, on the PHP side there's a variable which catches this request and echoes it. Here's the code :

```
$newTransaction = $_POST['newTransaction'];
echo $newTransaction;
```

What is wrong and/or how it should be better to resolve this issue?

Comment: well `xmlhttp.send({newTransaction});` will give you a *new* object with a single property called "newTransaction" with the value being a reference to your `newTransaction` variable. You probably just want `xmlhttp.send(newTransaction);` without the extra `{ }`.

Comment: @Pointy — Since they are trying to read a property called `newTransaction` in the PHP, that is probably intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong.

1. You are not converting your object to JSON before you send it: `xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({newTransaction}));`. Instead you are sending the default string representation of an object: `"[object Object]"` which isn't helpful.
2. Your PHP is expecting to receive URL encoded or Multipart form data. It is not expecting to receive JSON. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/19068)

Answer (score -1):

An `XmlHttpRequest` or `Ajax` for short is a requests that will not reload the page, with this logic you are sending a `POST` request like you would do in a form, when you send a form, you're sending a pair `key : values` to the file you're sending lets say you have a form like this

```
<input name="transactionID">
<input name="time">
<input name="senders">
<input name="receivers">
<input name="finalSum">
```

the values will be received like this in the global `$_POST` array

```
{
    "transactionID": "some id",
    "time": "some time",
    "senders": "some senders",
    "receivers": "some receivers",
    "finalSum": "final sum"
}
```

when you do a Ajax request, you do the same but without the `inputs html`, when you send the data like this

```
newTransaction.data = {
    "transactionID": document.getElementById('trans-id').value,
    "time": document.getElementById('creation-time').value,
    "senders": getSenders(),
    "receivers": getReceivers(),
    "finalSum": setSum()
};
xmlhttp.send({newTransaction});
```

In your `admin.php` you will receive something like

```
{
    "data" : {
        {
            "transactionID": "some id",
            "time": "some time",
            "senders": "some senders",
            "receivers": "some receivers",
            "finalSum": "final sum"
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend you 2 thigns

1. in your admin.php use `echo var_dump($_POST);die();` to see exactly what are you receiving
2. use a plugin to perform the ajax call like jQuery, axios, etc. this will give you tools to better handling the request and responses.